# How to load .mat images file using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Hi Im new to MATLAB and I've been trying to figure out how to load a faces1000.mat file and a nonfaces1000.mat images using MATLAB, I have a code for load_mnist which is

```
mnist_file = 'scrambled_mnist10000.bin';
fid = fopen(mnist_file, 'r');

[number, count] = fread(fid, 1, 'int32');
if count ~= 1
     disp('failed to read number');
end

[mnist_permutation, count] = fread(fid, number, 'int32');
if count ~= mnist_permutation
     disp('failed to read number');
end


 [mnist_labels, count] = fread(fid, number, 'uchar');
if count ~= number
    disp('failed to read number');
end

mnist_digits = fread(fid, [28, 28 * number], 'uchar');
mnist_digits = reshape(mnist_digits, [28, 28, number]);

fclose(fid);
disp('loaded mnist digits');
```

Im just not sure if I should load my faces1000.mat and nonfaces1000.mat images file the same way. I would appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can load .mat files this way

```
% Load entire mat file contents into a structure.
% The structure has a member "I" that is a double 512x512 array.
storedStructure = load('Data.mat');
% Extract out the image from the structure into its own variable.
% Don't use I as the variable name - bad for several reasons.
imageArray = storedStructure.s.I;  % Or storedStructure.I depending on what members your structure has.
% Display the image in a brand new figure window.
figure(1);
% Display double image, scaled appropriately.
% No need to cast to uint8 - could even be bad
% if your double numbers don't span the 0-255 range nicely.
imshow(imageArray, []);
```

This is based on a post from a MATLAB forum.

[Load an image from .mat](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/23195-display-mat-file-as-an-image)